# Are separable F-spaces (completely metrizable topological vector space) homeomorphic to $l_2$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, locally-convex-spaces, hilbert-manifolds

An F-space is a completely metrizable topological vector space, i.e. the vector topology is induced by a complete metric. A Fréchet space is, by definition, a locally convex F-space.

It is known that all (infinite dimensional) separable Fréchet spaces are homeomorphic to $l_2$, the space of square summable sequences of real numbers. (See *e.g.* Anderson, R. D.; Bing, R. H., *A complete elementary proof that Hilbert space is homeomorphic to the countable infinite product of lines.* Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. 74, 1968, 771–792.)

More precisely any such space, including $l_2$ is homeomorphic to a countable infinite product of copies of real lines.

> Can this result be extended to (any) non-locally convex F-spaces?

I am interested in any reference or recent literature on the topology (homeomorphism class) of F-spaces.

More precisely, I am interested in the following examples: $L_p([0,1])$ or $l_p$ with $0<p<1$, which are in fact quasi-Banach spaces. Meaning, the p-sum/integral defines a quasi-norm only, that is $||f+g||_p\leq K(||f||_p+||g||_p)$, holds only for a uniform constant $K>1$. Nevertheless $d(f,g)=||f-g||_p^p$ is a complete metric inducing the vector topology.

This question arose when wondering if $l_p$ has a structure of a Hilbert manifold.

Comment: The Mazur mappings shows that every $\ell_p$, respectively, $L_p$ is  homeomorphic to $\ell_2$, respectively, $L_2$, and hence all are homeomorphic.

Comment: Thank you for this comment. The extension to $0<p<1$ of Mazur's proof was done by A. Weston in his thesis. The following paper by him on uniform homeomorphisms of $L^p(\mu)$ spaces contains the needed inequalities. 
( https://maths-proceedings.anu.edu.au/CMAProcVol29/CMAProcVol29-Weston.pdf )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a famous linear metric space constructed by R. Cauty [Un espace métrique linéaire qui n'est pas un rétracte absolu, Fund. Math. 146 (1994)] whose completion is a  **separable $F$-space which is not an AR**. I do not have Cauty's paper handy but the latter fact is stated on the first page of    [Cauty's space enhanced](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166864111003257)  in
[Topology Appl. 159 (2012), no. 1, 28–33].

Since $\ell_2$ is an AR, the above $F$-space is not homeomorphic to $\ell_2$.

Incidentally, a separable $F$-space is homeomorphic to $\ell_2$ if and only if it is a non-locally-compact  AR, see Corollary 5.2.2 in [Absorbing sets in Infinite-Dimensional Manifolds, T. Banakh, T. Radul, M. Zarichnyi].

Comment: Here's the science direct link:
http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166864111003257

Comment: I think if we add the requirement that the separable, completetely metrisable $F$-space is an AR, we do have that is homeomorphic to $\ell_2$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: $\mathbb R^n$ is a counterexample to what you claim.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek everything is meant  to be infinite-dimensional of course.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: Then you are right: a topological vector space is locally compact iff finite-dimensional.